# how to print form results below the form

Tags: php, html

How to display results after form submission below the form itself in the submission page? I am trying to display the submitted results below the html form in the same page. How I can achieve it?

Comment: show us what you have tried

Comment: Display your code

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example for insert record from form and show that record on same time of insertion on same page modify code as per your requirement, I hope this will help you

```
   <?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database_name');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $message = $_POST['message'];
     $query = "INSERT INTO `table_name`(`name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$name."','".$message."')";
      mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    }
    ?>

    <form role="form" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="name">
      <input type="text" name="message">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
    </form>

    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); ?>
          <table>
            <tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Message</th></tr>
        <?php    
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):;
        ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['message'];?></td></tr>
    <?php
        endwhile;
    ?>
        </table>
```